# Extract part of tar file with absolute paths using 7zip

Tags: tar, absolute, 7zip

I'm trying to extract files from a tar file on a windows 7 machine using 7Zip's 7za.exe the command line. The file is 700GB and I only need a specific subdirectory. This should be possible using the following command.

```
7za x -r test.zip folder\subfolder
```

Running this on a test file (test.zip) does what is expected, i.e. it extracts all (sub)files from the folder\subfolder in the zip file. However, for the tar file, it doesn't work. I think it is related to a difference in file listings, as exemplified below.

```
7za l test.zip
```

produces:

```
folder
folder\subfolder
folder\subfolder\on_ADJ.png
```

While

```
7za l 20150602.tar
```

produces (excerpt):

```
.\Corpus
.\Corpus\DOC
.\Corpus\DOC\manual.pdf
```

Parallel to the first command, I tried using the following command.

```
7za x -r 20150602.tar .\Corpus\DOC
```

However, it doesn't work. Working within quotes (".\Corpus\DOC") or without .\ doesn't work either and 7Zip produces the following error.

```
Cannot use absolute pathnames for this command
```

Am I right that the tar file has absolute paths in it? If so, how could I solve this problem without having to extract the whole file?